# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). FITTING ERROR MACHINE LERNING

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

This is my code:

```
#Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
print(accuracy_score(prediction, y_test))
```

this is my error:

```
ValueError Traceback ( most recent call last )
<ipython-input-46-6d6525f64959> in <module>()
      2 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
      3 clf = GaussianNB()
----> 4 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
      5 prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
      6 scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     58                     msg_err.format
     59                     (type_err,
---> 60                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
     61             )
     62     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I am trying to use naive bayes method to teach the machine but i keep getting this error.

Comment: The error is quite clear. What are the values of `X_train` and `Y_train`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data has NaN values. Drop them. Use this code.

```
X_train = X_train.dropna()
#Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
```

This code will remove rows which contains NaN values. If you want to fill NaN instead of dropping them, you can fill those NaNs with the mean of their column using `.fillna(np.mean(column_name))`.